# array of char for linux make context

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I"m trying to write a code that uses makecontext in linux 32 bit
The man file holds the following code

```
   #include <ucontext.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   static ucontext_t uctx_main, uctx_func1, uctx_func2;

   //function here

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       char func1_stack[16384];
       char func2_stack[16384];

       if (getcontext(&uctx_func1) == -1)
           handle_error("getcontext");
       uctx_func1.uc_stack.ss_sp = func1_stack;
       uctx_func1.uc_stack.ss_size = sizeof(func1_stack);
       uctx_func1.uc_link = &uctx_main;
       makecontext(&uctx_func1, func1, 0);
       // other context code
```

How do I make this code suitable for more contexts, my main problem is how do I create an array of `char funcN_stack`?
I want this code to be build in a function with N size of function and contexts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how you create an array of N 16384 byte buffers (for stack use):

```
/* assumption: N is #defined */

char *stacks[N];
int i;
for (i=0; i<N; i++)
{
    stacks[i] = malloc(16384);
    /* add error handling here if malloc returns NULL */
}
```

Then use `stacks[x]` for the address of the buffer. Note you cannot use `sizeof` (as `stacks[i]` is a simple pointer not an array), so must either use 16384 direct, or better use a constant or `#define`.

Comment: After doing what you sugest do i simply write `uctx_funcx.uc_stack.ss_sp = staks[x];`

Comment: Or even better, have an array of `ucontext`s too.